# oracle sql query using group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following schema,

**Student**(FirstName,LastName,SID)
**Enrolled**(StudentID,CourseID)
**Course**(CID, CourseName,Department)

I need to figure out which students took more `CSC` classes than `IT`. The `CSC` and `IT` bit are found in the `Department` category. I have the following query which lists all the students who enrolled in courses and how many `CSC` courses they enrolled in.

```
select studentid,count(department) as cscclasses
from enrolled
left join course
on courseid = cid
and department = 'CSC'
group by studentid;
```

Not quite sure how to compare this count with those enrolled in IT courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to use `sum` and `case`

```
select studentid
from(
    select studentid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN department='CSC'
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                  END) as cscclasses,
        SUM(CASE WHEN department='IT'
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                  END) as itclasses
    from enrolled
    left join course
    on courseid = cid
    and department = 'CSC' OR department = 'IT'
    group by studentid
)
where cscclasses > itclasses
```

Answer (score 1):

In CTE , each student's CSC and IT course count is calculated

```
   With CTE
   As
  (
         select studentid,
            SUM(case when 
             department ='CSC' 
             then 1 else 0 
             end) as CSCCount ,
            SUM(case when 
             department ='IT' 
             then 1 else 0 
             end) as ITCount ,
         from enrolled
         left join course
         on courseid = cid
        And Sid =studentid
        group by studentid
  )
 Select E.* FROM
JOIN CTE
On CTE.studentid = E.sid
Where CTE.CSCCount >      CTE.ITCount
```